# Error c2061 when compiling

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

When I compile a project I get this error:

> C:\DATOSA~1\FAXENG~1>nmake /f
>   Makefile.vc  clean
>
> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance
>   Utility Version 9.00.21022.08
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. 
>   All rights reserved.
>
> ```
>     cd src
>     nmake /nologo /f Makefile.vc clean
>     del /F *.obj *.lib *.dll *.exe *.res *.exp
>     cd..
>     cd tools
>     nmake /nologo /f Makefile.vc clean
>     del *.obj *.lib *.dll *.exe
>     No se encuentra C:\DATOSA~1\FAXENG~1\tools\*.obj
>     cd ..
> ```
>
> C:\DATOSA~1\FAXENG~1>nmake /f
>   Makefile.vc
>
> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance
>   Utility Version 9.00.21022.08
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. 
>   All rights reserved.
>
> ```
>     cd src
>     nmake /nologo /f Makefile.vc
>     cl /nologo /MT /W3 /EHsc /O2 /I "..\..\tiff-3.8.2\libtiff" /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /c ClassOne.cpp ClassOne.cpp
>     cl /nologo /MT /W3 /EHsc /O2 /I "..\..\tiff-3.8.2\libtiff" /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /c ClassOnePointZero. ClassOnePointZero.cpp
>     cl /nologo /MT /W3 /EHsc /O2 /I "..\..\tiff-3.8.2\libtiff" /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /c ClassTwo.cpp ClassTwo.cpp
>     cl /nologo /MT /W3 /EHsc /O2 /I "..\..\tiff-3.8.2\libtiff" /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /c ClassTwoPointOne.c ClassTwoPointOne.cpp
>     cl /nologo /MT /W3 /EHsc /O2 /I "..\..\tiff-3.8.2\libtiff" /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /c ClassTwoPointZero. ClassTwoPointZero.cpp
>     cl /nologo /MT /W3 /EHsc /O2 /I "..\..\tiff-3.8.2\libtiff" /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /c ClassZero.cpp ClassZero.cpp
>     cl /nologo /MT /W3 /EHsc /O2 /I "..\..\tiff-3.8.2\libtiff" /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /c CommPort.cpp CommPort.cpp
>     cl /nologo /MT /W3 /EHsc /O2 /I "..\..\tiff-3.8.2\libtiff" /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /c ECMBuffer.cpp ECMBuffer.cpp
>     cl /nologo /MT /W3 /EHsc /O2 /I "..\..\tiff-3.8.2\libtiff" /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /c excepthandler.cpp excepthandler.cpp
>     cl /nologo /MT /W3 /EHsc /O2 /I "..\..\tiff-3.8.2\libtiff" /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /c FaxAPI.cpp FaxAPI.cpp
>     FaxAPI.cpp(143) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CClassZero'
>     NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2' Stop.
>     NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\nmake.EXE"' : return code '0x2' Stop.
> ```

The only thing I did was copy and paste ClassTwoPointOne files into ClassZero files and change names...

ClassTwoPointOne.h:

```
#ifndef CLASSTWOPOINTONE_H
#define CLASSTWOPOINTONE_H

#include "ClassTwoPointZero.h"

class CClassTwoPointOne : public CClassTwoPointZero
{
public:
    CClassTwoPointOne();
    virtual ~CClassTwoPointOne();

    virtual void SetFClass(void);
};

#endif // CLASSTWOPOINTONE_H
```

ClassTwoPointOne.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ClassTwoPointOne.h"

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Construction/Destruction
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

CClassTwoPointOne::CClassTwoPointOne()
{
    m_sEIAClass = "2.1";
    m_nScanTime = 0;
}

CClassTwoPointOne::~CClassTwoPointOne()
{

}

void CClassTwoPointOne::SetFClass(void)
{
    SendCommand( COMMAND_SET_FCLASS_2_1);
}
```

ClassZero.h:

```
#ifndef CLASSZERO_H
#define CLASSZERO_H

#include "VoiceModem.h"

class CClassZero : public CVoiceModem
{
public:
    CClassZero();
    virtual ~CClassZero();
};

#endif // CLASSZERO_H
```

ClassZero.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ClassZero.h"

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Construction/Destruction
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

CClassZero::CClassZero()
{
}

CClassZero::~CClassZero()
{
}
```

I don't understand whats wrong... anyone can help?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What line are you getting the error on, and what is the description of the error?

Comment: You'll have to show us FaxAPI.cpp around line 143.

Comment: Perhaps you should tag this with the compiler you're using. No?

Comment: It's visual studio 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **FaxAPI.cpp(143) : error C2061: syntax**
>   **error : identifier 'CClassZero'**

The error is at or near line number **143**, in file **FaxAPI.cpp**.
The error is related to the identifier **CClassZero**

(Possibly being undefined, or misused.  Possibly something as mundane as a missing semicolon).

If you cannot find the error in FaxAPI.cpp yourself, you need to provide us with the relevant part of that file.

Comment: There was an include missing... line 143 was: 

case FAXAPI_CLASS_0:
pMdm = new CClassZero;
break;

Thanks for pointing out that something could be missing from or undefined. I was convinced the code from this file was ok.

Answer (score 1):

msdn says c2061: "The compiler found an identifier where it wasn't expected. Make sure that identifier is declared before you use it." So apparently class CClassZero became undeclared after you messed with the files, makesure that you include appropriate files and that they contain a valid declaration  of class CClassZero